# What to do with missing days from timeseries when checking for seasonality?

Tags: python, missing-data, seasonality, pandas

I have a dataset which looks like this, with pm25 values and timestamp as index:

```
    pm25
2021-01-24  19.323319
2021-01-25  5.711776
2021-01-26  12.394315
2021-01-27  9.960435
2021-01-28  13.411006
... ...
2021-12-09  26.608724
2021-12-10  29.786922
2021-12-11  28.983176
2021-12-12  11.622958
2021-12-13  11.271967
311 rows × 1 columns
```

The issue is that between 24.01.21 and 13.12.21 there are more than 311 days, which I have in the dataset. Should I fill the dataset with the missing dates and input some pm25 values for those or should I leave it live that?

This is how the data looks like:

[image: pm25 values over time]

I would like to study if it has seasonality, but I cannot check it with the missing dates. What is the best option to solve this? I am preparing the data for LSTM forecasting.